# Query multiple Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have the following sheets:

- ListA
- ListB
- ListC

Note: at each sheet I have a column which contains YES or NO.

How do I query all my lists (spreadsheets) where myBooleanColumn equals to YES/NO?

Comment: What are you looking for? Just a count of the Yes/No's in each list on a 4th, separate sheet?

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter: Imagine that I have multiple lists and I wan to appear the rows that have been marked with ”YES/NO” at a certain column. Looked up to forums, blogs and other websites but haven't managed to reach to correct formula. Do you have an ideea?

Comment: @el.severo: Please [edit] your question to include this important information. Comments are impermanent.

Comment: Would it be possible to share an example spreadsheet ? That would make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your sheets are in the same spreadsheet and the range of interest is A:B where column B have values YES/NO and you want only the rows where B is equal to YES, then the following formula should work:

```
=QUERY({ListA!A:B;ListB!A:B;ListC!A:B}, "select Col1, Col2 where Col2='YES'")
```

**References**
[QUERY - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=es)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm going to assume you mean multiple SHEETS within the same SPREADSHEET. I know Google Spreadsheets can't search between multiple SPREADSHEETS.

Here is the formula to count the Yeses in a column (or row):

```
=COUNTIF(Q2:Q375,YES)
```

You could put one of these on each sheet and then sum them on a "report" sheet or cell. If you didn't want that count visible on each sheet put the cell out of range somewhere.

If you only want to show the YES rows on a sheet then use the built in filtering functions.